# Jeep Cherokee Electrical

Tags: electrical, battery, jeep, 4wd, cherokee

I have a 1991 Jeep Cherokee Laredo 4x4. When im driving all my electrical stuff turns off but turn on right away but the engine keeps running. This only happens when im driving through rough terrain, when i come to a stop and i start to accelerate, or when i hit a bump or dip. I replaced the battery and i checked for loose cables at the battery terminal but didnt find any.
Any idea what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the other end of the cables for security and tightness.

There will also be a bonding strap between engine and chassis / body or gearbox to body - usually across a rubber mount. These can break and cause the symptoms you describe.